# Set newly generated entry into page item oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have following case I would like to insert data into a table when a button is clicked.
In the same time I want to return the newly generated ID from the table and set this value in the page item.

I proceeded as follows:
created a process with following pl/sql code:

```
declare
l_user_id USERS.ID%TYPE;

begin
 INSERT INTO USERS(ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL) VALUES
 (:P9_ID,:P9_FIRSTNAME,:P9_LASTNAME,:P9_EMAIL)
 returning ID into l_user_id;

INSERT INTO MANAGER(UUID,MID) VALUES
(l_user_id,:P9_MID)


end;
```

The process works fine, the data is inserted into the tables, but the value of the page item is not set. After the insertion.
my question is, is there any way to retrieve a just generated ID or generally a just generated entry from the table and put it in a page element?

Comment: Can you provide details on what "does not work as hoped"?  You should be able to just assign the value to `:P9_ID` rather than calling `apex_util.set_session_state` but that probably isn't the source of whatever issue you have.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using a form region (available since 19.1) ? You don't have to write any insert statements yourself and you have to option to return the primary key value into a page item.

Answer (score 1):

How about another approach?

Set `P9_ID` item's source (or default value?) to sequence (`user_id_seq.nextval`).

I presume that this process runs when you push a button (i.e. submit the page). Therefore, when you do so, `P9_ID`'s value will be put into session state and you'd then insert it into a table.

```
begin
  insert into users (id, firstname, lastname, email) 
    values
    (:P9_ID, :P9_FIRSTNAME, :P9_LASTNAME, :P109_EMAIL);     --> is it really P109?
end;
```

and later use for whatever you plan to use it.

Comment: Hello:) I edited my question a little bit, I tried your approach, unfortunately no items are set when I add I new Manager and the insert process gets executed. However I can see that the items are set, but I cannot see the values appear in the page item:/